# Why was this question migrated from Stack Overflow to EE.SE, and can we please revert that?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, migration

[Does cpu work like gpu when it comes to prediction and if statements?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283084/does-cpu-work-like-gpu-when-it-comes-to-prediction-and-if-statements)

is clearly formulated in a way that emphasizes what the programming-technical differences between GPU and CPUs are.

It's hence a programming question, and I can't find it covered under the topics in the Electronics.SE help center (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

It is especially **not**

> the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

but it specifically **is**

> Programming software for a PC

So for me, this is clearly off-topic; at the point of asking, at least 11 people seem to [agree](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283084/does-cpu-work-like-gpu-when-it-comes-to-prediction-and-if-statements/283087#comment645420_283084) with me.

So:

- Why did we do this migration?
- How to revert it?

Comment: I'm not sure it belongs on SO, it's not exactly a practical programming question. Maybe a CS site? But it shouldn't just bounce all over the place, that sucks for the OP.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't see how it's a CS question - it's really all about specific tips on what to do when not doing GPU programming; I think it's too "practical" for CS. In any case, not an electronics/design/EE theory question, at all.

Comment: If understand how the migration process works it'll be bounced back here once it's closed on the destination site.

Comment: Hey, I'm the idjit who did the migration. To answer your questions: 1. It was asked for migration by a user with10k on that site(mods have got instructions from Shog stating that if a 1k+user asks for migration go ahead) 2. Close it on the other side, it'll come back. I'll remove the notices and close the post as too broad. (We'll lose the good answers there though, but I don't think that's a problem)

Comment: @BhargavRao no reason to call yourself names :) If someone with high "target rep" asked me, well, I might just comply out of good faith!

Comment: @BhargavRao since I hate the witchhunting, I'll anonymize this info, post it as answer here, and will remove my comments (so that you can remove yours, too)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Erm, There's no witchhunting here, I've not mentioned the flaggers name as it's against the mod agreement. But yep, Posting it as answer and accepting it would make this a good post for further questions asking for the same. :)

Comment: in that case, I wanted to keep the torches and pitchforks away from you, @BhargavRao, but, yeah, none would benefit from knowing the flagger's name, so there's nothing to be won if you did.

Comment: Oh, Thanks @Marcus, But my name is there in the [revisions of the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41920236/revisions), so can't keep those away. :D

Comment: @BhargavRao ha, now I'm the idjit – I could have just contacted you if I had paid detailed attention to who the mod was on that migration *doh*.

Comment: Lol, Yep. But anyway it's now a nice meta post (as I can't see another dupe). So it'll be helpful in future. :)

Comment: yeah! Will have to come back in 2 days, @BhargavRao, when I can accept my own answer.

Comment: [It is "Stack Overflow", not "StackOverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks! Oh shoot, that means I might have to change that in more than one place.

Comment: _"if a 1k+user asks for migration go ahead"_ In the current climate, I think this threshold (at least on SO) should be much, much higher. The 10k number itself might be a better tipping point, though it's worth pointing out that this 10k user got it wrong ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit afai understood, the point was that the person requesting the migration was high-rep on the *target* site, i.e. EE.SE; I'd agree, for larger sites like EE, that threshold would be relatively low, but for smaller ones like ham.SE and even DSP.SE, it'd be a pretty high threshold. I don't think it's feasible to have a rule like "top 5% user" or so

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yeah, target or source, on SO 1k is not much.

Comment: Seems like the question is too broad no matter where it is.

Answer (score 17):

Turns out the question was migrated by a SO mod to EE.SE on request of a high-rep user on the target site. This was a good-faith operation.

The correct way to deal with this seems to be closing the question on EE.SE, which will revert the migration.

Answer (score 7):

This is an odd case. It seems to be a reasonable and legitimately scoped question for whatever site it would be appropriate for:

- Stack Overflow: not a specific programming problem.
- Electronics: not low-level enough.
- Computer Graphics: not actually about GPUs.
- Software Engineering: ?

Maybe SE is the best place for it.

BTW: the answer to the question is "no".

Comment: Are you missing the word "not" a few places here? I'm confused about how it can be "a reasonable and legitimately scoped question", but then have all these problems.

Comment: @CodyGray: He means: it is reasonable and legitimately scoped for whatever site it is on-topic on … but unfortunately, it isn't on-topic on any existing site in the SE network. Being off-topic and being a bad question are different types of problems. One can be fixed by migration / deletion+re-asking, the other can't.

Comment: BTW: I disagree with that interpretation. Personally, I find the question too broad. There are thousands of different CPUs with wildly different behavior, there is no way to answer this question without knowing what *specific* CPU the OP is asking about. For example, while Apple's G5 CPU, the Cell BE's PPE in the PlayStation 3, and the Xenon in the XBox 360 are all PowerPC 970 cores and have identical ISAs, they differ *specifically* in the fact that the Cell BE PPE and the Xenon core are stripped of most of their branch prediction and out-of-order logic.

Comment: @JörgWMittag from the literal wording, I'd agree with you. From the context and level of understanding OP shows, clearly a PC-style CPU vs Shader-Model-Style GPGPU question. Not Cell vs. Larrabee, not RISC-V vs atari GPU. Very clearly x86/ARM-app-proc CPU vs current-gen Nvidia/AMD/Intel GPU

Answer (score 3):

This question would be on-topic on SO with just some slight modifications to make it more specific. If the OP could name one specific CPU and one specific GPU and ask about their differences in handling branching, then I believe it would be a narrow enough question for SO.

The question is not on-topic on EE, since it is not about firmware, nor about electronics.

Comment: if you agree with closing it on EE.SE, could you help by close-voting in that manner?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Being a SW guy, I haven't got nearly as much rep on EE as I do here. (But apparently enough to ask moderators to migrate stuff around, muahaha!) So I can only flag the question for closing, not cast close votes directly.

Comment: Agreed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342521/why-was-this-question-migrated-from-stack-overflow-to-ee-se-and-can-we-please-r/342531#comment439556_342531