# Comments suggesting OP to move off-topic question to appropriate site are getting removed

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I'm active in several tags, which are notorious for getting loads of off-topic questions (for example [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh)).

I vote these question to be closed as off-topic and I usually post a comment saying:

> (Welcome to Stack Overflow.) Please move your question to [Super User](https://superuser.com) (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

For example:

- [Pasword less authentication only using the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58909225/850848)
- [How to connect SFTP using SSH credentials in FileZilla?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58897748/850848)

---

In the last few weeks I often notice that my comments are removed.

Few examples of questions, where my comments were removed:

- [Network error: software caused connection abort windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58836413/850848)
- [trying to create a putty.log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58869588/850848)
- [How to enable active mode using stateful filtering - FTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58672443/850848)

I know that comments can be removed for number of reasons. But I do not think my comments are not relevant or rude.

Is there a reason for that? Am I wrong posting such comments? Should I stop that?

Comment: @yivi: For unpopular tags, leaving a comment is a mercy for the new user. It may take days, months, or longer, to get enough close votes for the user to see the automated suggestion to go to another site.

Comment: Leaving additional comment is fine. They may vanish but most likely OP will see them before that. The only thing I would change in your comment is rephrasing "move to xx site" and add additional note for OP to check if their question is following the rules of that particular site before asking there.

Answer (score 4):

If you believe the question is off-topic here, just vote to close. If you believe it should be migrated to another site, vote to migrate. No need to leave those comments.

You seem to be experienced in both Stack Overflow and the site's you are advising to re post in, but most comments I've seen of this type come from users who are not as experienced, and are **very often** misguided in many ways.

And having these comments laying around simply encourage other users to leave more of the same.

In any case, comments exist to "ask for clarification and add more information". These comments are most often deleted as "no longer needed", since they are not doing either.

Mods are not going to check the tags a question has, or when has the comment been posted and what's the 'last-seen' status for the user receiving the comment, nor how many close votes the question has or has not when reviewing "no longer needed" flags. These comments will be flagged, and generally flags will be honoured.

They are not rude or unkind, so there is no penalty. But best to accept their ephemeral nature.

It's not "wrong" to leave them, but you should accept that many of these are going to be deleted soonish anyway. More often than not the target for the comment had time to read them before deletion, so they are really **no longer needed**.

And if they are not paying attention to comments after posting their question, and the comments get deleted before they have a chance to read them... well, in all likelihood there weren't all that engaged in getting help anyway.

Comment: According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371652/considering-changing-the-migration-process), by a moderator at the time, *"[the moderators] are reluctant to migrate anything, __unless the flagger has a high rep on the target site__"* (emphasis mine). So a good avenue could be for the post to be diamond flagged, for this user and this site (not in general).

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- If the comment stays at least few days, I would agree. But the comment is sometimes deleted the very same day. That's way too quick imo. + *"simply encourage other users to leave more of the same"* - Isn't it other way around? Removing the comment encourages others to re-post similar comment. As for example happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58869588/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl basically you disagree with the fact that most activity on questions happen while post is 1-2 hours old and pretty much no moderation activity after that... It's almost as useful to disagree with current weather :)

Comment: A question is either on-topic - than you don't need such comment, or off-topic with supported migration target (like SU) - than close as such, or off-topic without migration target - than close with custom reason (which is likely to stay long enough and get support with other similar close votes)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But isn't it better if we make OP migrate the question? That way the reviewers do not have to deal with the question and can spend their valuable time with other posts.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl "If you want a thing done well, do it yourself." (claimed to be by Napoleon Bonaparte) - if you feel question is awesome for other site just migrate yoursefl… I don't see how you can "make OP migrate the question" - most OP don't even reply to comments and presumably just pick answer in several days (no acceptance either)… Closing the question does not prevent OP to migrate and keeps site clean - not exactly sure, but it sounds like you prefer to keep off-topic questions open in hope OP will eventually migrate it...